# How you retrieve the Key<T> when you have an Entity?

Tags: objectify, google-app-engine

I have a class that I loaded using Objectify v5, how do I get the associated `Key<T>` from Objectify?

```java
@Entity
@Cache
public abstract class BaseEntity<T,P>
{
    @Parent
    private Key<P> parent;

    @Id
    private String uuid;
}
```

I know that `ofy().save()` returns the `Key<T>` but I want to get the `Key<T>` from an `Entity` that was loaded by a filter or id.

#### I have searched all over the Objectify v5 documentation and can't find methods that take an `Entity` and return a `Key<T>` of that Entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

```
Key.create(T pojo);
```

But in the case above it doesn't work from inside my `BaseEntity<T,P>` class.

```
@Nonnull
public Key<T> getKey() { return Key.create(this); }
```

Complains that it wants to cast the result to `Key<T>`.

After some experimenting I just added a method to my `BaseEntity`

```
@Nonnull
public Key<T> getKey() 
{ 
    return Key.create(this.parent, this.entityType, this.uuid.toString()); 
}
```

This returns the same `Key<T>` that is auto-generated.

Comment: Can you provide an example of exactly what you're trying to do? This sounds like a Java generics question. You may need to cast the create function, e.g. `Key.<SomeType>create(...)`.

Answer (score -1):

Java's typing system is not sophisticated enough to express "i want this to be whatever type 'this' happens to be at the leaf level" (since you are in an abstract class). Scala could do this, but not Java. At least not to my knowledge.

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you are trying to do...?

Comment: Ah i see what you were trying to do now. Are you typing the Base class -- via T -- on the concrete class that represents it. MyEntity extends Base<MyEntity, SomeP>? Also, is the #entityType a method that returns T and you must override in subclasses to return this.getClass()? Thanks.